# If a class is annotated as @istest why do the test methods within the class need that annotation?

Tags: apex

If a class is annotated as @istest why do the test methods within the class need that annotation?

So, for example:

```
@isTest
private class myTestClass
{
    @isTest static void test1(){...}; //current convention

    static void test2(){...}; //why not this?

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you can put "helper" methods in the class. They don't run by themselves, but are used to do things like initialize records, set up variables, etc.

For example:

```
public static void init() {
  insert new Account(Name=...);
  ...
}
@isTest static void test1() {
  init();
  ...
}
@isTest static void test2() {
  init();
  ...
}
```